# opening a tiff image in IE

Tags: html, tiff

Is it possible to open Tiff images in IE, just like BMP opens in IE.
When i try to assign an iframe source as a tiff image it pops up a save dialog. i want to display tiff image inside an IE page.

Following is a sample which i was trying

```
<iframe src='C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Untitled.tif'; id ='hello'></iframe>
```

Comment: BMP are opened by IE only because it is the native Windows image format. Any other non-Web image format is unlikely to be opened by a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE does not natively support TIFF images.  You have three options:

1. Use a browser plugin such as: http://www.alternatiff.com/
2. Convert the image on the fly before presenting to the browser.
3. Batch convert the images to another format.

The preferred solution will depend on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't support TIFF images natively. You need a plugin for this to work. Check http://www.alternatiff.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try the classic "applet" instead...

Comment: Can you provide more details.